# How write shell part in declarative jenkins pipeline to groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have work with Jenkins and haven't competencies in groovy. I have scheme where jenkins need call proxy teamcity and download ftp or sftp when path for artefact not from local network.
I have write declarative pipeline but can't transfer that in groovy.

```
    stage('read JSON') {
        steps {
            script{
                
                def projects = readJSON file: "json-files/json.json"
                
                supply.repo=projects.repo
                echo "${supply.repo}"
            }
        }
    }
    
    stage('test download') {
        steps {
            script {
               try { 
                 sh """
                  if echo "${supply.repo}" | grep -q "domain"; then
                     echo "${supply.repo}"
                     mkdir artefact
                    wget "${supply.repo}" -P artefact
                  else
                    exit 1
                  fi
                  """
                }
                catch (exc) {
                 build( "ftp-tc" )
                 parameters {
                 ...........
                 }
                 echo 'Something failed, I should sound the klaxons!'
             }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what do you want. The pipeline itself is a groovy script, but the pipeline as-is does not run on a local machine because it does not have access to the pipeline special steps like: `sh`, `build`, `readJSON` and so on. Beside these special steps, everyhting else is groovy, e.g. `try ... catch`.

Comment: This part not work in jenkins its install on windows 
And i want it's run on windows .
'
if echo "${supply.repo}" | grep -q "domain"; then
                     echo "${supply.repo}"
                     mkdir artefact
                    wget "${supply.repo}" -P artefact
                  else
                    exit 1
                  fi
                  """
'

Comment: If you want a bash script run on windows, then this is another topic, it is not groovy related.

Comment: I don't want run bash in windows, i want write bash logics for working in windows like groovy syntax. (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_if_else_statement.htm )

Comment: That's better, but then I suggest you to rewrite the question because is confusing.